# Powershell | Find similar files by name(Name.txt/Name (01).txt/ Name (02).txt) in a directory and delete all except last modified

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a folder in which i download working files, usually all versions of the files have the same name, so windows mark tham as "name (01).ext", "name (02).ext" and so on. I need to write a script that deletes every copy EXCEPT last modified. For now my script working perfectly if folder contains only one pack of similar files, but if there are a lot of them, that it deletes everything except only one last modified.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Re\* -Include *.txt, *.rtf  |
  Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Split('\ \(\d\)', 2)[0] } |
  Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -SkipLast 1 } |
  Remove-Item -Force
```

I think that the problem is in
 `Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Split('\ \(\d\)', 2)[0] } |`
as its puts every single found file in one single group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.split()` method does not use regex, the `-split` operator does. I believe it would work fine if you changed it to

```
  Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Re\* -Include *.txt, *.rtf  |
    Group-Object { ($_.BaseName -Split '\ \(\d\)')[0] } |
    Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -SkipLast 1 } |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Also note with any single property operation in the `*-Object` cmdlets you can omit the braces `{ }` and automatic variable `$_`.

Comment: *"I've made a slight adjustment"* - That's just echoing what we already know. What we don't know is: Why? As a basic rule, a quality answer should contain at least what the issue is and how the proposed solution addresses the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I definitely want to provide quality answers.

Comment: @DougMaurer Ok, it works almost like a charm. The `($_.BaseName -Split '\ \(\d\)')[0]` is flawless, thanks a lot for that, but the one you suggested with -replace has minor bug with keeping the initial file not deleted (the one without numbers in it). Could you please do sth about it, maybe it would be useful for someone. Again, thanks a lot, you're breathtaking! :D